# Check Variable By If In Each Function

Tags: jquery, loops, if-statement

Sory for my bad english.

My question is: I have input that I wanna know if that input has inside table, it can not insert in table again. I insert it by jquery. This my jquery to check:

```
function onEnterimei(e) { // => Digunakan untuk membaca karakter enter
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (key == 13) { // => Karakter enter dikenali sebagai angka 13
        imei = document.getElementById("inputanimei").value;
        var hitung = document.getElementById("databarang").rows.length - 1;
        if (hitung == 0) {
            document.getElementById("inputanqty").focus();
        } else {
            var inpZ = $(document.getElementById("databarang"))
                .find('tbody input[rel = Aimei]');
            $(inpZ).each(function() {
                if (this.value!=imei){
                    document.getElementById("inputanqty").focus();
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("inputanimei").focus();
                }
            });
        }   

        document.getElementById("jumlahinputan").value = hitung;
    }
};
```

I can not post my html cause 4 indent and still can not read after many fix. Sory. I hope good answer. :)

Comment: If you want to share your HTML but can't manage to put it here, I suggest to use a [gist](https://gist.github.com/), [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)